# Workaround for PHP SOAP request failure when wsdl defines service port binding as https and port 80?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, port, soap-client

I am consuming a SOAP web service using php5's soap extension.  The service' wsdl was generated using Axis java2wsdl, and whatever options are used during generation result in the port binding url being listed as **https**://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx**:80**

If I download the wsdl to my server, remove the port 80 specification from the port binding location value, and reference the local file in my soapclient call it works fine.

However, if I try to reference it remotely (or download it and reference it locally, as-is) the call fails with a soap fault.

I have no input into the service side so I can't make them change their wsdl-generation process.  So, unless there's a way to make the soapclient ignorant of the port, I'm stuck with using a locally modified copy of someone else' wsdl (which I'd rather not do).

Any thoughts on how to make my soapclient ignore the port 80?

Comment: Do you get the soap fault already on Object construction (`new SoapClient()`) or at the first try to call a method of the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try overriding the hostname/port using the $options array that you can pass as the second argument to SoapClient's constructor:

`$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", 
                     array('proxy_host' => "https://example.org",
                           'proxy_port' => 443);`

Comment: Interesting.  So, let's say the url of the wsdl is https://example.org/service?wsdl and that the port binding in the wsdl is https://192.168.1.1:80/servicebinding (in this case, it's apparently load-balanced behind the example.org server).  Would my proxy_host then still be example.org?

I'll probably just need to experiment.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find a more elegant solution, you can always download the file, do the string replacements, then use that as the WSDL.

```
$cached_wsdl_file = './cached_wsdl.xml';
if (filemtime($cached_wsdl_file) > time() - 3600) {
    $wsdl = file_get_contents('http://server/service?wsdl');
    $wsdl = str_replace('server:80', 'server', $wsdl);
    file_put_contents($cached_wsdl_file, $wsdl);
}
$client = new SoapClient($cached_wsdl_file);
```