# PHP::SoapClient instead of Zend_Soap_Client in (Zend Server with Zend Framework Version 1.10.7)

Tags: zend-framework, soap-client, zend-server, zend-server-ce

I have all my SOAP Calls successfully working in PHP CORE (When I run them in WAMP) . But when I try to just add the same code to Zend Server,for some reason it says "The server encountered an internal error".
Not sure what is going on!
A call using `SoapClient()` is not at all working...
I am using Local WSDL and local soap service which is given by Alchemy.
Anyways,I tried the same with `Zend_Soap_Client` too,but still,it doesn't work!!
Here is the dump of Zend Soap Client created :

```
object(Zend_Soap_Client)#37 (29) { ["_encoding":protected]=> string(5) "UTF-8" ["_classmap":protected]=> NULL ["_faultExceptions":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_soapVersion":protected]=> int(2) ["_uri":protected]=> NULL ["_location":protected]=> NULL ["_style":protected]=> NULL ["_use":protected]=> NULL ["_login":protected]=> NULL ["_password":protected]=> NULL ["_proxy_host":protected]=> NULL ["_proxy_port":protected]=> NULL ["_proxy_login":protected]=> NULL ["_proxy_password":protected]=> NULL ["_local_cert":protected]=> NULL ["_passphrase":protected]=> NULL ["_compression":protected]=> NULL ["_connection_timeout":protected]=> NULL ["_stream_context":protected]=> NULL ["_features":protected]=> NULL ["_cache_wsdl":protected]=> NULL ["_user_agent":protected]=> NULL ["_wsdl":protected]=> string(77) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\C3Nexus\application\WSAlchemy.wsdl" ["_soapClient":protected]=> NULL ["_lastMethod":protected]=> string(0) "" ["_soapInputHeaders":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_permanentSoapInputHeaders":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_soapOutputHeaders":protected]=> array(0) { } ["location"]=> string(29) "http://localhost:3434/Alchemy"
```

Even a call like `getFunctions()` on the client is giving me the error.
What am I doing wrong?

Found these errors in ZendEnabler.log

```
[3/15/2013 2:21:55 PM] Error: Read data error - unable to get read result. Code 109.
[3/15/2013 2:21:55 PM] Error: Request for C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/SOME/public/index.php: Unable to get the response from PHP process
[3/15/2013 2:21:55 PM] Error: PHP process 9872 from the "application/x-httpd-php" pool has exited with status 255.
```

Url Request : `http://localhost:8089/SOME/public/index.php/NewPatient/load-gsdd-data`

Hence,

Controller :  `NewPatient`
Action : `loadGssdData`

I am writing soap call in that action.

This works:

```
$hey = new Zend_Soap_Client(APPLICATION_PATH . '\WSAlchemy.wsdl');
$hey->location ='http://localhost:3434/Alchemy';
echo var_dump($hey);
```

But fails when I call `$hey->getFunctions()` !

This doesn't work at all,

```
$hey = new SoapClient(APPLICATION_PATH . '\WSAlchemy.wsdl');
$hey->location ='http://localhost:3434/Alchemy';
echo var_dump($hey);
```

or even this!

```
 $hey = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8089/SOME/public/WSAlchemy.wsdl");
 echo var_dump($hey);
```

Note: I can access the wsdl file at `http://localhost:8089/SOME/public/WSAlchemy.wsdl`

I wonder why I can't use `SoapClient` in Zend Server,which is core PHP one !! :(

To try,I disabled Soap Client in Zend Server
It said :

```
[15-Mar-2013 14:46:23] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SoapClient' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\SOME\application\controllers\GSDD.php on line 2
```

So,I enabled again,it says no error there,still I get error! 
This is my server access log after enabling the extension :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2013:14:54:06 -0400] "POST /ZendServer/index.php/Log-Tail/Index HTTP/1.1" 200 9205
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2013:14:54:07 -0400] "POST /ZendServer/index.php?controller=systray&action=exec&do=ping HTTP/1.1" 200 643
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2013:14:54:35 -0400] "GET /SOME/public/index.php/NewPatient/load-gsdd-data HTTP/1.1" 500 499
```

So when I load I get this :

[image: Error]

After I open that file,there is server error in there.

Other controllers and actions are working fine! I just have problem with this action.

Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: Typically in your PHP log there will be a more informative error message the just '500 Internal server error'.  Suppose check dependencies.  `libxml` should be enabled and if you are using SSL with this service you should ensure `openssl` is setup.  Try disabling WSDL caching and turning [trace option](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) (debug) on with the SoapClient.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment . As I use Zend Server,I saw the logs at php_error,it shows nothing.I checked access logs,error logs,nothing is being displayed.For cache I did this `ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);  ` still no luck! Trace option is enabled by default by Zend. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Checked `error_reporting` level?  Not simply suppressing the errors?  Can't really debug an generic 'Internal Server Error'.

Comment: Found some logs,see updated post.Thanks

Comment: Do you have installed soap extension in your zend server installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,fixed it finally!

In the process,learned how things work,but,lol it is a silly reason!

`Zend was unable to read the Schema File`
That is it!!!

Small issue,phew!

Sorry if this question troubled you ;)

But yeah WSDL and Schema file must go hand in hand! How did I miss this!

Thanks to all for viewing this questions!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, having some deje vu.  Almost certainly the odd ball port number... openCM?  Does the WSDL   follow suit?  Try `'proxy_host'` and`'proxy_port'` with your SoapClient options?

Found this that might be same thing: [Workaround for PHP SOAP request failure when wsdl defines service port binding as https and port 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439615/workaround-for-php-soap-request-failure-when-wsdl-defines-service-port-binding-a)

Comment: Thanks for reply.But I am not using any proxy.I am running the server at `http://localhost:8089` and I am calling soap at port `3434` . So,should I put any `proxy_port` ? If so,to port `3434` ? As,I ran wamp at `8080`, and soap at `3434`,never set the `proxy_port` option had no problem! Adding on WSDL post, my WSDL file is local file,that means as you see in post,it is in `application` directory where the server has all source files . I am not using ssl too.ANyways,let me try adding host as `localhost` and port `8089`..

Comment: does it resolve in a browser?  `hosts` issue maybe, what else changed / differs from server A to server B...?

Comment: :( Nope din work! Well as the same code worked for wamp at `8080` , I don't actually see what could be wrong for `8089` (which is just apache given by Zend itself).Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Your hosts/vhost setup with Apache?  i.e. `NameVirtualHost` `*:8089`?

Comment: Well I am able to access the site.No problem there,there are lot of pages,it is working site.So shouldn't be problem with hosts.I am just trying to add a functionality to existing site,now I got problems just with that action..rest pages are good!