# Accessing SOAP method through WSDL with port binding PHP

Tags: php, soap, zend-framework2, soap-client

I am currently trying to consume a SOAP web service using Zend SOAP Client, but I am currently facing the problem of not being able to get to any of the methods because the post binding location address is different to that of the url I am accessing the WSDL from.

I have found this similar issue on SO already:

[Workaround for PHP SOAP request failure when wsdl defines service port binding as https and port 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439615/workaround-for-php-soap-request-failure-when-wsdl-defines-service-port-binding-a)

But the comment the OP asked here

[Workaround for PHP SOAP request failure when wsdl defines service port binding as https and port 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439615/workaround-for-php-soap-request-failure-when-wsdl-defines-service-port-binding-a#comment1286053_1439744)

is what I am currently looking for a answer for.

This is the error I currently get when I make the call to the WSDL

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://xxxx.xxx.xx:9076/inventory?wsdl=InventoryWSSoap.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://xxxx.xxx.xx:9076/inventory?wsdl=InventoryWSSoap.wsdl"
```

Here is my code

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$apiUrl = "https://testurl.com/inventory?wsdl";

try {
    $client = new Zend\Soap\Client($apiUrl, array(
        'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT,
        'proxy_port' => 9076,
    ));

    $params = array(
        'name' => 'usnema',
        'pwd' => 'xxxxx',
        'operatorId' => '11210210'
    );
    $adSpace = $client->GetAdSpaceList($params);

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($adSpace);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: is your web service live

Comment: Yeah its a live web service.